# working with jsp simple form along with java code

Tags: jsp

i am new to java and jsp..
I have done a java code, i would like to add this java code into jsp
Initially shown a web page to getting input from user
once the user enter the information, it will call a java function

please let me know how to do this.. please..

```
public void createXmlTree(String name){
        Writer output = null;
        String addtext = "";            
        File file = new File("compare.txt");
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        output.write(name);
        output.close();
}
String name1;
name1 = request.getParameter("text1");   
String name=name1;

try
{
  if (!(name.equals(null))) {
   createXmlTree(name);
   out.println("Successfull");
  }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: I think you just need to search for a tutorial about "Java Servlets" which will show you the basics. You should then read about "Expression Language" for outputting parameter values to the JSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn [servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Let the HTML form in the JSP submit to a servlet.

```
<form action="servleturl" method="post">
```

In the `doPost()` method of the servlet class you've all freedom to write Java code the way you want. When the business job is finished, you could store the result in request scope and forward to a result JSP file.

```
request.setAttribute("result", result);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/result.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

In the `/WEB-INF/result.jsp` you can access the result by [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info).

```
<p>Result: ${result}</p>
```